Kafka connect only creates three topics out of a list of 7 tables
I ahve this configuration for kafka connect
name=jdbc-source-connector-oracle-1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=3
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@o22.opsdb-prl.int.iag.cloud:1521:O22
connection.user=
connection.password= 



table.whitelist=tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5, tbl6, tbl7
topic.prefix=tbl_
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=TASK_ID
poll.interval.ms=900000
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
offset.storage.file.filename="/tmp/task-allocation-offsets.txt"
transforms=InsertTopic
transforms.InsertTopic.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
transforms.InsertTopic.topic.field=messageTopic

Why does kafka connect only create 3 topics. Just randomly it is creating three topics instead of 7 topics. Also can anyone explain what does tasks.max property do?


only create 3 topics

It should create 11

randomly it is creating three topics

Yes, those are internal topics for utilities.

can anyone explain what does tasks.max property do?

For JDBC source - nothing, since it is limited to just 1. Otherwise, imagine if you were using MirrorMaker2, then the tasks should equal the amount of partitions to distrubue

Suggest reading through https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.1/connect/concepts.html#connectors
